# problem with onChange event on react input type file event on safari browsers

Tags: reactjs, safari, onchange

I have a project written in ReactJs. The upload files works fine except on safari browser. In fact the on change event is firing on input type file.

Comment: I have the same issue. If the onChange event is present, the FileList is always empty.  Without onChange it works. The combination seems to be the problem. Only in Safari.